# how to get current process listening ports in .net core?

Tags: .net-core, netstat

create a cmd process and call `netstat` may get listening ports, but it's complicated and create may be slowly, any build-in method can does this?

I found `IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpListeners()`, but this will return all tcp listener and without process info.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get current `Address:Port`, which i figure out, while starting the project.

The **critical** thing is that `you must define at least once 'ASPNETCORE_URLS'` somehow from out-source. If you dont do that .net core `doesn't set DefaultEnpoints` which causes unreachable `address:port` directly.

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        String ServerAddress = app.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses.FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine($"ServerInfo: {ServerAddress}");
        ...
    }
```

**CMD (Windows)**

```
set ASPNETCORE_URLS = http://localhost:2020 && dotnet MyProject.dll
```

**Docker**

```
docker run --rm -it -p 2020:80 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://localhost:2020" MyProjectImage
```

**note:**

*if try without using environment variable(ASPNETCORE_URLS), you will see empty Addresses collection*